# C++ singleton class by making the constructor private

Tags: c++, singleton

I tried to use the pattern to make a class practically a singleton by making the constructor non-public. However, when I tested it, the result is not what I expected. If only one instance is created, the `value` should be the same for the references, but apparently, they are different like below. What is wrong with the code?

Code:

```
class SortOfSingleton
{
public:
    static SortOfSingleton& getInstance();
    int value = 0;
private:
    SortOfSingleton(int value);
};

SortOfSingleton::SortOfSingleton(int value)
{
    std::cout << "Creating new instance."<< std::endl;
    this->value = value;
}

SortOfSingleton& SortOfSingleton::getInstance()
{
    static SortOfSingleton instance(5);
    return instance;
}


void main()
{
    auto instance1 = SortOfSingleton::getInstance();
    instance1.value = 100;
    std::cout << instance1.value << std::endl;

    auto instance2 = SortOfSingleton::getInstance();
    std::cout << instance2.value << std::endl;
```

Real Output:

```
Creating new instance.
100
5
```

Expected Output:

```
Creating new instance.
100
100
```

Comment: You need to get rid of the copy constructor the compiler provides for you if you wake an actual singleton.  Also to note, `auto` will never deduce a reference type.  You need `auto& variable_name = ...;` if you wan to get a reference.

Comment: Note: `void main()` is not a valid `main` declaration. It should be `int main()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` type deduction does *not* include references. Instead each `instance` variable will be its own *copy* of the object.

You must explicitly use `&` to define a reference:

```
auto& instance1 = SortOfSingleton::getInstance();

...

auto& instance2 = SortOfSingleton::getInstance();
```

---

On that note you need to disallow copying as well, by deleting the copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator. You should also disallow moving the object with the rvalue overloads.